# Java code snippet - playing with variable final - explanation required

Tags: java, variables, final

```
final Integer a = 1;
Integer b = a;

System.out.println("a: " + a); // prints 1
System.out.println("b: " + b); // prints 1

b++;
System.out.println("a: " + a); // prints 1
System.out.println("b: " + b); // prints 2

b = b + 1;
System.out.println("a: " + a); // prints 1
System.out.println("b: " + b); // prints 3

b = 10;
System.out.println("a: " + a); // prints 1
System.out.println("b: " + b); // prints 10
```

It would be great if somebody could explain the code output, expecially with relation to variable B.

Comment: Your output is wrong.  After `b++`, `b` prints `2`.  Then, it prints `3`, and finally `10`.  I just ran your code verbatim.

Comment: I modified your question to reflect actual output.  Given that nothing strikes me as odd about the output, could you clarify what is confusing you?

Comment: I was using eclipses jpage/scrappage facility, hence the confusion that b++ didn't work like i would have wanted it to.
Running it as a java class gave the result you state above and exactly the one I was expecting.

I guess eclipse scrappage implementation has a bug.

Comment: In this case please try to add another print out after that b++
This may it be cause of that the value b was not evluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, let's start with this:

```
final Integer a = 1;
```

You've created a final **reference** to an Integer object, which was autoboxed from a primitive int.

This **reference** can be assigned exactly once, and never again.

```
Integer b = a;
```

here you've created a second reference to the same object, but this reference is not final, so you can reassign it at your leisure.

```
b++;
```

This is a shorthand for the following statement:

```
b = new Integer(b.intValue() + 1);
```

And, coincidentally, the same for

```
b = b + 1;
```

The last statement:

```
b = 10
```

Is using autoboxing to shorthand this statement:

```
b = new Integer(10);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe autoboxing uses `Integer.valueOf`, not `new Integer`.

Comment: You're probably right - I was more interested in the concepts than the specifics. In that it creates a new one (or returns from the internal cache) for the assignment.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter for this example, but I believe it uses `Integer.valueOf(...)` and not `new Integer(...)` so `==` still works.

Comment: But why if b++  is b = new Integer(b.intValue() +1) then print out print 1 ? 

This is standard post incremenation so the b have the value 2 in case after that sysout

Comment: Thank you very much. Eclipse scrappage wasn't outputing the correct value for b++, hence the confusion.
Much appreciate your input, its really informative.

Comment: @j flemm: Never, ever, ever count on that in real code.  Just way too easy to make mistakes, even if the JLS specifies a minimum integer cache size.  `==` only works if the value the Integer represents is within the pool of cached integers.

Comment: @Mark Peter: At the begining in the code sample the result was 1, after some time, it was changed to 2.

Comment: @Mark Peters: I never would. `.equals(...)` is there for a reason. But `new Integer(...)` is usually regarded as bad form since it's never better and possibly worse. I just used `==` to check it in my IDE since I wasn't in the mood to check the bytecode.

Comment: Oh absolutely, `new Integer(int)` is always wrong.  If they could design it from scratch they'd probably make the constructor private.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you must know that auto-boxing is happening here, [you can read about that here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Now only the `b++` strikes me as non-straightforward.  It is functionally equivalent to this code:

```
int bTemp = b.intValue();
bTemp++;
b = Integer.valueOf(bTemp);
```

Though the bytecode may be slightly different.